# How do I request permissions for users information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, sdk, oauth

I think this is a very obvious question, but I am completely stumped. I think I have setup my app settings correctly, but when I try to authenticate (with Javascript SDK) my account on my website and then console.log(me), I still only get public information.

EDIT: I think that my problem is that my website is using the "Current Dialog" and not the "Referral Dialog." I understand that the referral dialog is only used when someone is directed to my website through Facebook, but I know there must be a way to use the Referral Dialog from my website as well. Why would anyone even use the Current Dialog if it can only authenticate the server with a user's public information? I read another post that said I should look at the authentication doc (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), but as far as I can see there is nothing there on authorizing with the Referral Dialog.

I want to use Javascript SDK. Is this possible or will I have to just do it without Javascript SDK?

In Auth Dialog, I have this: email, user_about_me, user_likes, user_location, user_website, user_checkins

Here is my code:

```
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  // Init the SDK upon load
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '464723870207650', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/scripts/channel.php', // Path to your Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
        FB.api('/me', function(me){
            console.log(me);
        })
      } else {
        // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
      }
    });
  }
```

When I run it through the debugger, I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method along with the wanted permissions:

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        console.log("FB.login callback, response: ", response);
    }, { scope: "email,publish_stream,etc" });
}
```

Just keep in mind that:

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.